# Is there a way to get a character's ASCII code in sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I'm writing a sed script part of which requires replacing characters from a certain subset with the hexadecimal values of their ASCII codes. I did some research and I could not find anything, so I'm starting to think that sed does not have a feature that would let me do that.   If there are any sed gurus here, could you please enlighten me?

P.S.: solutions like `sed -e "s/A/41/g" -e "s/B/42/g"... etc` won't do.

Comment: Is [`awk`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-29) a suitable replacement?

Comment: I guess so, it's not imperative that I use sed. I just don't know awk, but as long as it gets the job done...

Comment: Is perl a suitable replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>while IFS= read -r -n1 c; do printf '%x' "'$c"; done < infile > outfile</strike>

No, `sed`'s 's' command can only convert characters to their lower/upper case counterparts, it doesn't have a facility to replace them with their equivalent ascii code.  There is the 'y' command for transliteration but that requires a 1-for-1 mapping in length, so that won't work.

Without seeing your code, my best recommendation is a move to `awk`

Comment: I don't want to replace ALL the characters in the input, only those that match certain criteria. I could've used xxd for that purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

If perl is a viable alternative to you, then:

```
fge@erwin ~ $ perl -pe 's,[abcRte], ord($&) ,ge'
oiiiiisdfa
oiiiiisdf97
abcRte
97989982116101
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
ord () { printf '%d' "'$1"; }
hex () { printf '%x' "'$1"; }
export -f ord hex
echo {a..z} | sed '/[f-m]/s//$(ord &)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/' | sh
a b c d e 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 n o p q r s t u v w x y z
echo {a..z} | sed '/[f-m]/s//$(hex &)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/' | sh
a b c d e 66 67 68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

If you have GNU sed:

```
sed '/[f-m]/s//$(ord &)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e'
```

or

```
sed '/[f-m]/s//$(hex &)/g;s/.*/echo "&"/e'
```